# Several inner joins producing too many rows

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

I'm working on a field trip request software for school districts.

Each field trip has an account attached to it that will be billed.  It will also have one or more driver/vehicle combinations and mileage and driver rates associated with each driver/vehicle combination.

I'm working on an accounting report that will show, by account, a count of the trips that are assigned to that account, the total number of miles driven on that account times a certain charge basis, and a total number of hours each driver has driven on that trip multiplied by their payrate.

I have a field trip (tripid=1) with two vehicles and two drivers and I expect two rows of output.  However, I am getting 4 rows; Two rows for vehicle 81 and two rows for vehicle 56.  Is there something in my joins that's causing too many rows to be outputted?

What's weird is Mister Driver is on both vehicles in the output of my query and so is Generic Person.

```
select distinct
       tdv.tripid as tripid,
       ta.name as account,
       cb.chargebasisname as trip_type,
       cb.defaultdistancerate as distance_rate,
       (tc.odometerreturn-tc.odometerstart) as total_miles,
       datediff(hour, tc.actualoriginstarttime,tc.actualoriginreturntime) as total_hours,
       v.vehicle,
       pr.hourlyrate as driver_rate,
       e.firstname+' '+e.lastname as driver

from trip_tripdrivervehicle tdv

join trip_tripinformation ti
on ti.recordid = tdv.tripid

join trip_transportationaccounts ta
on ta.recordid = ti.accountid

join trip_invoicechargebasis cb
on cb.recordid = ta.defaultchargebasisid

join trip_tripcompletion tc
on tc.tripid = ti.recordid

join vehicles v
on v.recordid = tc.vehicleid

join trip_employeejobcategorypayrate pr
on pr.employeeid = tdv.driverid

join employees e
on e.recordid = tdv.driverid

where ti.triprequeststatusid = 7 and ti.recordid = 1
```

Here is my output:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_Bbr20KcwLyw/TX5cwDhr7BI/AAAAAAAAbYE/qCfQtk6Xmeg/s800/sql_results.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you also have two matches for the JOIN with table `trip_tripcompletion` - one that gives rows with total miles of 10 and another that gives rows with total miles of 50.

So each driver shows up with each total_miles option.

The JOIN condition for this table may need to be changed, or you can use `GROUP BY` along with `MAX/MIN` to show only the shortest/longest trip (depending on the need).

Comment: Galz, Thanks for the tip. How could I adjust the JOIN with the trip_tripcompletion to show only the desired results?  I tried an outer join but the results still spit out 4 rows instead of the desired 2.

I have made an image showing the results I'm looking for here:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_Bbr20KcwLyw/TYCwPhjsgfI/AAAAAAAAbZU/DfmL-hN2WSM/s800/desired_output.jpg

Comment: @JJBladester - I will need some more info: how is the 50 miles trip related to MISTER DRIVER and how is the 10 miles trip related to GENERIC PERSON? is there any column in `trip_tripcompletion` which relates to the driver? If there isn't, why do you expect to get this output and not the opposite? (50 miles for GENERIC PERSON and 10 for MISTER DRIVER?)

Comment: Got it figured out (with your help). My revised code is below. Now I need to get a count of the number of field trips taken per account. I need a distinct count, so if TripID shows up multiple times for an account, it should only be counted once like this:

http://tinyurl.com/4nhx2o6

inner join trip_tripdrivervehicle tdv on tdv.tripid = ti.recordid 
and tdv.vehicleID = v.RecordID

So, you can see the fix was the "and tdv.vehicleID = v.RecordID
" piece to add an additional restriction to the join.